# Remove file commited in old commit

Tags: git, commit, git-history

I have 6 commits and each of them have multiple files commited. My "problem" is, that I commited a file which I should not commit, and I want it to dissapear from that old commit, so I can‘t see it:

```
last commit
  file8
  file7

commit 3
  file6
  file5

commit 2
  file4
  file3

first commit
  file2
  file1
```

How can I remove file4 from commit 2 to disappear?

```
...
commit 3
  file6
  file5

commit 2
  file3

...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can to this with following command. But first find out the path to the file in your repository where you want to remove (`file4`).

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch <path_to_file>" HEAD
```

After this, execute `git push -f` and the file is removed from the `commit2` and from the repository.

**BUT BE CAREFUL WITH** `git filter-branch`. The documentation you can see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)

Comment: Note that this makes *new and different commits*, as I explain in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68374435/1256452).  It does not alter, nor remove, the old commit, and some hosting systems (such as GitHub) won't expire the old commit the way Git eventually will.

Answer (score -3):

You can't.  *No* commit, once made, can *ever be changed*.  So you can't remove the file from the old commit.

This does not mean you cannot solve your *real* problem, which is: you'd like to still have six commits, but you'd like the *contents* of some of those six commits to be *different* than they are now.  You can achieve this by making several *new* commits, after which you *stop using* some of the old commits.

If commit #1 is OK, you can keep that one around as-is.  Commit #2, which follows #1, however, is *not* OK.  You must throw that one out.  You can't actually discard or delete it directly, but you can *stop using it*.  Once you do that, Git will eventually discard it.<sup>1</sup>  You will, however, need a *new and improved version* of commit #2, that you will use instead of the old commit-#2.

Commit #3 might be partly OK, if it doesn't contain the file you don't want any of the commits to contain.<sup>2</sup>  But even if it is OK this way, it's definitely *not* okay after all, because it *refers to the bad commit #2*.  Every Git commit refers back to its immediate predecessor, so to replace commit #2, you must strip out commit #3 as well.  This means you will need to make a replacement for #3.

Commit #4 might be partly OK, like #3, but like #3, it refers back to a bad commit: in this case, #3 itself!  #3 is bad *because* it refers directly to #2, and that makes #4 bad too.  So you're going to have to make a new-and-improved version of commit #4.

This repeats down the line with commits #5 and #6.  If commit #2 is bad, you *must* replace it with a new-and-improved version, and that necessitates replacing every *subsequent* commit as well.

So: how you do you go about replacing these commits?  This is where `git rebase` comes in.  What `git rebase` does—what it's all about—is taking some existing commits, that are sort of mostly OK in some way or another, but not OK in some other way—and *replacing* them with new-and-improved commits.

The `git rebase` command does this with `git cherry-pick` internally.  It's a good idea to understand this and know how it all works.  This has been quite well covered in [other StackOverflow postings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41464752/1256452), [though](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56118047/1256452), [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35704829/1256452) [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53300939/1256452) [those](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+git+rebase+interactive+new+and+improved+commit).

You can also use `git filter-branch` (which is now formally deprecated) or its replacement, `git filter-repo`, to copy the existing commits to new-and-improved commits.  See [SwissCodeMen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68375576/1256452) for an example.  Remember that this makes *new and improved* commits: the originals still exist for some time, perhaps forever on GitHub for instance.

---

<sup>1</sup>By default, disused commits stick around for at least 30 days, in case you change your mind and want them back.  It's hard to *find* them once they're like this, and it's rarely worth trying to speed up the default-at-least-30-days aging thing that Git does with them, but if you have an odd situation, it is possible to accelerate the process.

<sup>2</sup>Every commit contains *every* file, not just changed files since the previous commit.  So if commit #3 doesn't *remove* the file, as compared with commit #2, it's not OK after all.  But that's a side point because of the way we'll build the new-and-improved commits.

Comment: As far as I know, this is possible with the following command: `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file" HEAD` -> look at my answer. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen: filter-branch also copies commits to new-and-improved commits. However, it's not a very user-usable command.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that `git filter branch` isn't a very user usable command. But I have tried it now, and the file was removed in commit X without creating/copying another commit ... So I think it is possible, but to be used/executed with caution.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen: But it did (create a new commit, and then a bunch more new commits down the line). Compare the *hash IDs* before and after the filter-branch. Don't just count up the commits! Also, run `git log --all --decorate --graph` afterward to see the original commits under the `refs/original/refs/heads/` names.